# How to solve promise rejection: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**CouponStack.js**

```js
const Coupon = {
  screen: CouponScreen,
  params: { updated: null },
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  }),
};
const CouponDetail = {
  screen: CouponDetailScreen,
  navigationOptions: () => ({
  }),
};

const CouponStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Coupon,
    CouponDetail,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Coupon',
    navigationOptions: {
    },
  },
);

export default CouponStack;
```

**Index.js**

```js
export default class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      typeOne: [],
      typeTwo: [],
      typeThree: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
  }

  async shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.navigation.state.params.updated) {
      const { updated } = prevProps.navigation.state.params;
      // updated = object
      const { typeTwo, typeThree } = this.state;
      // typeThree = []
      this.setState({
        typeTwo: typeTwo.filter((v) => v.id !== updated.id),
        typeThree: [...typeThree, updated],
      });
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
    );
  }
}
```

**Detail.js**

```js
export default class Detail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      coupon: this.props.navigation.state.params.coupon,
    };
  }


  backToIndex() {
    const updated = this.state.coupon;
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Index', { updated });
  }
}
```

**What I'm trying to do**

When navigating from Detail to Index, I want to `setState` again.

So, I'm using `shouldComponentUpdate` in Index.js.

**error**

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.]

It looks like Index.js repeatedly calls setState when navigating to Index from Detail.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve this.

Comment: You `CANNOT` have `setState()` inside `shouldComponentUpdate()`. It's supposed to return only `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: Please read the API docs

Comment: @codemax Thanks. Should I use componentDidUpdate() in this case?

Comment: @user14212874 Yes, it's safe to use `setState()` inside `componentDidUpdate()`. Be careful not to catch another stack error. Refer to [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).